# Redefine macro in macro with parameter

Tags: macros, parameters

I've been trying this for hours now. Probably is something simple I missed...

I have a macro `\newcommand{\cf}[1]{\footnote{Cf. #1}}` (usage usually `\cf{\cite{xx}}`). Now I want to extend it, that it remembers which reference I used last, and if it is the same again, does not print the citation but "Ibd." instead.

Thus I modified it like

```
\newcommand{\cf}[1]{
  Cf.    
  \ifthenelse{\equals{\SVE}{#1}}{%
    ibd.}{%
    #1
    \def\SVE#1
  }
}
```

But that does not work. `\SVE` remains empty (or however I initialized it first). I experimented a lot till now, putting `\expandafter`s, `\noexpand`s,... around like crazy... But no result.

-- Edit:

Heres the full code copied:

```
\documentclass{article}

% somewhere in my preamble
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\LLfootnoteLastCite}{}
\newcommand\LLfootnoteCite[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\LLfootnoteLastCite}{#1}}{%
        ibd.}{%
        #1%
        \def\LLfootnoteLastCite{#1}%
    }%
}
\newcommand{\LLfootnote}[3]{\footnote{#3~#2\ifx#10\else, S. #1\fi.}}

% the exposed commands
\newcommand{\vgl}[2][0]{\LLfootnote{#1}{\LLfootnoteCite{#2}}{Vgl.}}


% small working example
\begin{document}
  This is a\vgl{\cite{Reference}}. And this is the second\vgl{\cite{Reference}}. And this is a third\vgl{\cite{Reference2}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Christian
How "full" should the example be? like containing \documentclass  \begin{document}... ?

Comment: Exactly -- compilable, but reduced to the real issue

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\if...\fi` is not a group

Comment: Are you aware that many packages for typesetting citations and bibliographies can do this for you? If you use Biblatex/Biber, you can usually just add the relevant option when loading Biblatex, for example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: True, I confused it with something different

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks, I'll do it upfront the next time ;)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand\SVE{}% initialize

\newcommand{\cf}[1]{%you need this %
  Cf.    
  \ifthenelse{\equal% \equal not \equals
       {\SVE}{#1}}{%
    ibd.}{%
    #1% you need thi s%
    \def\SVE{#1}% braces are mandatory for \def
  }% you need this %
}
\begin{document}

\cf{aaa} \cf{aaa} \cf{zzz} \cf{zzz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So now that's spooky. Your code does exactly what it should, mine looks the same (as far as I can tell) but does not. I edited my original question to show the full code I use... And thanks for your comments, those I actually had already correct in the orginal but messed up when trying to simplify my question.

Comment: Probably it has something to do with \cite{...} ? Thats at least what made me try various versions...

Comment: @AlexanderNiederklapfer you have edited the question since the answer was posted (which makes the archive hard to follow) but I put comments in my code where it differed from yours. Notably you had a syntax error of missing braces for `\def`. you can't test `\cite` with `\equal` you don't want to test `\cite `but just the string used as a cite key.